# Security audit framework of Internet Explorer Outlook Web Access (OWA) add-on?

Tags: audit, internet-explorer

I'm working with a software company that has developed an add-on to Outlook Web Access. They are aggregating data and providing a consolidated view of a particular topic / category. I have experience with data center security audits for Saas companies with web GUIs. I was wondering if there are other areas of concern related to add-ons that I should be sure to vet before an external audit.

Thanks!
Swalsh

Comment: this is pretty broad, please narrow your question to some specifics...

Comment: Thanks for the input, Mathew. I edited my original question. Does that help?

Comment: While you have certainly narrowed down the question, it is still a bit broad because you are asking for [any] 'areas of concern' regarding add-ons (presumably the IE OWA). I suggest that you specify (in the post not the subjectline) what the addon is but more importantly, outline what youre most concerned about IE what threats.